# Upload files doesn't work on Ejabberd server

Tags: ejabberd

I will try to explain to you what is happening to me in my brand new Ejabberd server. I can not get the option to upload files between users (mod_http_upload), I have followed several tutorials, but there is no way. I use port 5443, as it comes in the default configuration, with TLS enabled, but it does not work. I have used clients on android mobile and desktop, same result. In the server logs it shows that it even creates a "slot" of the files, but never uploads them. I have also reviewed access permissions to the folders involved, but it does not work either. I start to be a little desperate, I hope someone helps me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I've been struggling with a similar problem for a while now. Since this is one of the first posts I found while trying to find an answer to this problem on the Internet, I'm going to leave my explanation here of how I got file upload working on ejabberd in case anyone finds themselves in a similar situation.

I'm going to assume that you've got your ejabberd up and running. Below are the [relevant items of the configuration](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-http-upload) I had to tweak to get file upload working.

For starters, there's the authorization. The `mod_http_upload` module has an `access` option. This option matches the access rule that controls access to the file upload service. Its default value is `local`. This means you need to pick an alternative, either:

- Create an access rule called `local` and use it to authorize whoever you want to be able to upload files.
- Or change the access option in the `mod_http_upload` configuration to point to a rule of your own making.

In my case, I took the second route. I created a new rule called `file_upload` and configured the `mod_http_upload` to use it.

```yaml
acl:
  # ...
  local:
    server:
      - "example.com"
  # ...

access_rules:
  # ...
  file_upload:
    allow: local
  # ...

modules:
  # ...
  mod_http_upload:
    access: file_upload
    # ...
```

Once this is done, your local users will be able to request file upload slots. However, there's a second part, which is configuring `mod_http_upload` as the handler for an `/upload` endpoint on port 5443 (or whichever port you are using for the `ejabberd_http` module).

This involves two steps:

1. Enable the handler in the listen section of the configuration.
2. Inform `mod_http_upload` about your endpoint. Here's how it looks in my configuration file:

```yaml
listen:
  # ...
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      /upload: mod_http_upload
      # ...

modules:
  # ...
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: "https://@HOST@:5443/upload"
    # ...
```

Of course, you also need to ensure that ejabberd can write to your docroot folder. Additionally, if you want XMPP standards compliance, you need to [set some custom headers](https://www.process-one.net/blog/how-to-configure-ejabberd-to-get-100-in-xmpp-compliance-test/).

In the end, my full `mod_http_upload` configuration for ejabberd version 24.02 looks like this:

```yaml
hosts:
  - "example.com"

log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_count: 5
loglevel: debug

acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - "root@example.com"
  local:
    server:
      - "example.com"
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::ffff:127.0.0.1/128

access_rules:
  configure:
    allow: admin
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  file_upload:
    allow: local

shaper_rules:
  max_user_offline_messages:
    - 5000: all
  hard_upload_quota:
    - 16: all
  soft_upload_quota:
    - 12: all

certfiles:
  - "/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
  - "/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    access: c2s
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    starttls: true
    starttls_required: true
    max_stanza_size: 262144
  -
    port: 5223
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    access: c2s
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    tls: true
    max_stanza_size: 262144
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    shaper: s2s_shaper
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5270
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    shaper: s2s_shaper
    tls: true
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /upload: mod_http_upload
  -
    port: 3478
    transport: udp
    module: ejabberd_stun
    use_turn: true
    turn_min_port: 49152
    turn_max_port: 65535
    turn_ipv4_address: # my public IP address
  -
    port: 5349
    transport: tcp
    module: ejabberd_stun
    use_turn: true
    tls: true
    turn_min_port: 49152
    turn_max_port: 65535
    ip: 0.0.0.0
    turn_ipv4_address: # my public IP address

modules:
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_disco:
    server_info:
      -
        modules: all
        name: abuse-addresses
        urls: ["mailto:root@example.com"]
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    access: file_upload
    put_url: "https://@HOST@:5443/upload"
    docroot: "/home/ejabberd/upload"
    custom_headers:
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://@HOST@"
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS"
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
  mod_http_upload_quota:
    max_days: 3
  mod_jidprep: {}
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: always
  mod_muc:
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true
      anonymous: false
      mam: true
      members_only: true
      public: false
      public_list: false
    history_size: 0
  mod_muc_admin:
    subscribe_room_many_max_users: 100
  mod_muc_occupantid: {}
  mod_offline:
    store_groupchat: true
    use_mam_for_storage: true
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_pres_counter: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push:
    include_body: true
    include_sender: true
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_stream_mgmt: {}
  mod_stun_disco:
    credentials_lifetime: 12h
    services:
      -
        host: # my public IP address
        port: 3478
        type: stun
        transport: udp
        restricted: false
      -
        host: # my public IP address
        port: 3478
        type: turn
        transport: udp
        restricted: true
      -
        host: example.com
        port: 5349
        type: stuns
        transport: tcp
        restricted: false
      -
        host: example.com
        port: 5349
        type: turns
        transport: tcp
        restricted: true
  mod_time: {}
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}

acme:
  auto: false
s2s_use_starttls: required
```

I hope that this can help anyone struggling with file upload in ejabberd.

Sources:

- https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-http-upload
- https://www.process-one.net/blog/how-to-configure-ejabberd-to-get-100-in-xmpp-compliance-test/